# Configured errorChannel not called after aggregation

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We are facing a strange behavior in our integration flows where the errorChannel does not receive a message in case an exception is thrown in a step *after* an aggregation.

This is the (reduced) flow:

```java
    @Bean
    public StandardIntegrationFlow startKafkaInbound() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Kafka
                .messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                        kafkaConsumerFactory,
                        ListenerMode.record,
                        serviceProperties.getInputTopic().getName())
                .errorChannel(errorHandler.getInputChannel())
        )
                .channel(nextChannel().getInputChannel())
                .get();
    }

@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow nextChannel() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("next")
                .transform(Transformers.fromJson(MyObject.class))  // An exception here is sent to errorChannel
                .aggregate(aggregatorSpec ->
                        aggregatorSpec
                                .releaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(100))
                                .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                                .groupTimeout(2000L)
                                .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                                .correlationStrategy(message -> KafkaHeaderUtils.getOrDefault(message.getHeaders(), MY_CORRELATION_HEADER, ""))
                )
                .transform(myObjectTransformer)  // Exception here is not sent to errorChannel                 
                .channel(acknowledgeMyObjectFlow().getInputChannel())
                .get();
    }
```

If we add an explicit channel which is not of type DirectChannel the errorHandling is working as expected. Working code looks like:

```java
// ...
.aggregate(aggregatorSpec -> ...)
.channel(MessageChannels.queue())
.transform(myObjectTransformer)  // Now the exception is sent to errorChannel                 
.channel(acknowledgeMyObjectFlow().getInputChannel())
// ...
```

Also we'd like to mention, that we have a very similar flow with an aggregation where errorHandling works as expected (Exception sent to errorChannel)

So we were actually able to get the code running, but since errorHandling is a very critical part of the application we'd really like to understand how we can ensure each error will be sent to the configured channel and why explicitly setting a QueueChannel leads to the wanted behavior.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this

```
.enrichHeaders(headers -> headers.header(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, (errorHandler.getInputChannel()))
```

before an aggregator.

The `.channel(MessageChannels.queue())` is misleading over here because the error is sent to the global `errorChannel`, which is apparently is the same as yours `errorHandler.getInputChannel()`.

The problem that `.groupTimeout(2000L)` is done on a separate `TaskScheduler` thread and when an error happens downstream there is no knowledge about `try..catch` in that `Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter`.

Feel free to raise a GH issue, so we will think about populating that `errorChannel` into message headers from the `MessageProducerSupport`, like that `Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter`. So, the error handling would be the same independently of the async nature of the downstream flow.

**UPDATE**

Please, try this as a solution:

```
.transform(Transformers.fromJson(MyDataObject.class))  // An exception here is sent to errorChannel
.enrichHeaders(headers -> headers.header(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, (errorHandler.getInputChannel())))
.aggregate(aggregatorSpec ->
```

The `enrichHeaders()` should do the trick to determine a proper error channel to send error.

Plus your `MyDataObjectTransformer` has to be modified to this:

```
   throw new MessageTransformationException(source, "test");
```

The point is that there is  a logic like this when exception is caught by the endpoint:

```
if (handler != null) {
        try {
            handler.handleMessage(message);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw IntegrationUtils.wrapInDeliveryExceptionIfNecessary(message,
                    () -> "Dispatcher failed to deliver Message", e);
        }
    }
```

where:

```
if (!(ex instanceof MessagingException) ||
            ((MessagingException) ex).getFailedMessage() == null) {
        runtimeException = new MessageDeliveryException(message, text.get(), ex);
    }
```

And then in the `AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler`:

```
catch (MessageDeliveryException ex) {
                                        logger.warn(ex, () ->
                                                "The MessageGroup [" + groupId +
                                                        "] is rescheduled by the reason of: ");
                                    scheduleGroupToForceComplete(groupId);
                                }
```

That's how your exception does not reach the error channel.
You may consider to not use that `MessageTransformationException`. The logic in the wrapping handler is like this:

```
protected Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> message) {
    try {
        return this.transformer.transform(message);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof MessageTransformationException) { // NOSONAR
            throw (MessageTransformationException) e;
        }
        throw new MessageTransformationException(message, "Failed to transform Message in " + this, e);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

OK. I see that you use Spring Boot and that one does not register a respective `ErrorHandler` to the `TaskScheduler` used in the aggregator for group timeout feature.

Please, consider to add this bean into your configuration:

```
@Bean
TaskSchedulerCustomizer taskSchedulerCustomizer(ErrorHandler integrationMessagePublishingErrorHandler) {
    return taskScheduler -> taskScheduler.setErrorHandler(integrationMessagePublishingErrorHandler);
}
```

And then feel free to raise a GH issue for Spring Boot to make this customization as a default one in the auto-configuration.

Comment: Actually I've tried this before and it's not working. My errorHandler.getInputChannel() is not the same as `errorChannel`, so I've tried to see whether the error is sent to `errorChannel` instead but no result. My actual aggregators also manipulate headers in .headersFunction() and set an dedicated errorChannel in `MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL` but the header is only used if I add that strange  `.channel(MessageChannels.queue())` to the flow. Do you have any further idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Yeah… what you say doesn’t to a simple use-case. Any chances to have a Spring Boot project to let us reproduce a play with?

Comment: I was able to create a minimal project to reproduce the issue. Anyway in my example the `.channel(MessageChannels.queue())` does not fix the issue... See: https://github.com/dspruth/spring-integration-errorchannel-sample

Comment: Thank you for your sample. It indeed helps. Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your updated answer. I've implemented the suggested changes (see example repo) but it doesn't solve the issue. Error is not sent to errorHandler

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE 2 in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your second update solved the issue. Could you please provide additional information where to open the GH issue? Is it in general spring-boot repository?

Comment: True , that’s the one : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues